# Why can't Rails 3.2.9 automatically require a *.rb file in the "lib" directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I realize that "lib" is no longer autoloaded by default. However, I have this in my application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/datatables)
```

I have a module in lib called `utility.rb`, declared as follows:

```
module MyApp
  module Utility
```

I have some utility methods in there, for example a method that takes an array and turns it into values that can be queried from MySQL. I have:

```
include MyApp
```

at the top of the classes that need that method, so that I can then just call:

```
Utility::array_to_query_string
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Whether running a rake task or the application, I am met with:

```
uninitialized constant MyApp
```

I don't know how to make Rails `require` other than what I have above. In the console, if I explicitly type `require 'utility'` and then I can successfully do the include. What do I have to do to make Rails autoload this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be the directory structure in your lib folder. That the rails autoloader can find your file, it needs to be placed in the right spot. Your `MyApp::Utility` module should live in a file called: `lib/my_app/utility.rb`.

If you place the file directly in lib `lib/utility.rb` the autoloader won't find it.

Comment: Works like a charm, that was they key piece of information I was missing. The module needs to live in a directory structure that reflects its declaration hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In some of my apps, I add an initializer that loads my custom code.

In config/initializers/utility.rb,

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/utility"
```

Comment: I think you should only do this for vendored code. This way you work around the rails autoloader and loose the ability to reload the code in your development environment. Also It's not necessary if you have the right directory structure in your autoloaded folders.

Comment: @YvesSenn Thank you for the comment. I investigated my projects where I'm having to use the aforementioned initializers and discovered that the ````config.autoload_paths```` was completely missing from my ````application.rb```` file.